# ORMLite foreign member updates

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I have a Top level element that I'm saving to the database, and it has several foreign elements, something like this:

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Parent {
    @DatabaseField(id = true, index = true)
    public Integer id;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    public ChildA a;
}

@DatabaseTable
public class ChildA {
    DatabaseField(generatedId = true, index = true)
    public Integer id;

    @DatabaseField
    public boolean something;
}
```

Assuming these have already been created in the database. And now I want to update them. Will calling `parentDao.update(parent)` update both? Or do I need to manually update the child as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is:

> no, it won't update both

Foreign objects are not proxy objects so there is no way for ORMLite to determine if the sub-object has been modified and needs to be updated.  So if you change both the `Parent` and `ChildA` objects then you'd have to do something like:

```
 childADao.update(parent.a);
 parentDao.update(parent);
```

Obviously, if you set a *new* ChildA on parent then it will update this new id in the parent table.